# iTextSharp - How to read the user password?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

i read a pdf file protected with a user password and then create a new document that should have the same user password as the original one.

The problem is that i can read the document with the user password without entering it 
but when i try to create the new file i do not know the user password so it is empty.

The new pdf file is password unprotected while i want it to have the same user password as the original one.

I do not want to ask the user for it , is there a way to compute it ?

What does the PdfReader.ComputeUserPassword() do ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a public computer at a coffee shop where everyone can login and use it to browse the internet but you need a special password to install any software. You, a customer at this coffee shop, want to setup a second computer that works that same way and has the same administrator password as the coffee shop's system. Short of hacking the coffee shop's computer, this isn't possible.

The same is true about PDF passwords. You might legally own the documents you are working on but the only solutions to this is to either obtain the true passwords from someone or write new ones.